# What is a better REST API? /car/{make}/{model}/drive OR /car/drive/{make}/{model}?

Tags: rest

I am creating a REST api and have the following example APIs:

A car can be

- created
- deleted
- driven
- returned as an array of models for a given make
- returned as an array of all cars

What format should the API take?  Does it matter?

Comment: I would likely go with something like: `/cars/{make}/{model}/drive`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `drive` is the verb, then you would want `/car/{make}/{model}/drive` because you are requesting a specific resource to drive.  In that case, you want a car that is of make `{make}` and of model `{model}`.  Once that resource is returned, you then 'drive' it.

The second doesn't make sense because you're specifying the verb and then the attributes for retrieving the resource after that.

Just as an aside, if you are striving for pure REST standards, I wouldn't use 'drive' as part of the API.  Your REST API should perform HTTP actions, such as `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder for HTTP actions and duplicating that with the URL.  Where would a hypothetical "Drive" go?  In my case I want a particular encrypted email to be validated (signature) or decrypted

Comment: Here is an interesting conversation on it on SO.  I tend to agree with the accepted answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676550/how-to-expose-a-validation-api-in-a-restful-way