# Naming convention to be followed for ReST API when the API needs to perform validation

Tags: rest, api-design

I have written an API which requires the contents of the payload to be verified first and then after confirmation, the same payload needs to be sent via another API call. Now these two APIs cannot be combined into a single one.

Considering the naming convention of not using any verb and restricting myself to only nouns, I cannot have it as `POST /api/v1/sensors/validate` which is what the API does exactly.

I can call it as `POST /api/v1/sensors/validation` or `POST /api/v1/sensors/draft`, but neither is as intuitive as the validate one. Under such situations, whats recommended approach?

*I understand this question almost borders on being termed as "opinion-based"*

Comment: Hi, Amit, similar to this question was answered in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676550/how-to-expose-a-validation-api-in-a-restful-way

Comment: What you basically have here is a draft version of a resource. In HTML you'd basically have a form where a user enters data sends it to the server and receives a response which he can work further upon. If the initial resource is valid the URI of the form could be different than before to proceed the task else it receives the same URI again to re-validate the changes. You could basically also store the draft temporarily on the server so that a client does not have to send the whole document twice. Note how the actual URI is not of importance here as the client just learns it from the response

Comment: BTW, the URI itself shouldn't convey meaning to a client and clients should not parse or analyze URIs anyway, hence the spelling of the URI is irrelevant. Chose whatever you like. To computers a URI with a verb in it is just as valid as a URI with UUIDs or what not. Hence, the no-verb-in-URIs rule is more of an individual preference